# What were the special powers of MeghanAda?

Tags: ramayana, siddhi, indrajit

Ravana's son MeghanAda was believed to possess mighty special powers and siddhis which made him almost impossible to defeat.

These shaktis also made it difficult for lord Rama's army to defeat him.

What were those special siddhis or maayaavi powers which made him invincible?

Answer (score 3):

**1 Indrajit (MeghanAda) performed many sacrifices and got powers (boons, weapons, sidhis etc):**

[image]

English Translation ([Source](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-30))

> O king ;thy son hath met with the fruits of many a sacrifice
>   ***Agnistoma*, *Asvamedha*, *Bahusuvarnaka*. *Rajasuya*, *Gomedha* and *Vaisnava***. And being engaged in this ***Maheshvara*** sacrifice, which is incapable of being celebrated by men, thy son hath obtained **boon from
>   Pasupati himself**. He has also **obtained illusory powers which create
>   darkness or ignorance namely of ranging in the sky**, of being eternal,
>   of ascending a celestial car which curses at will and of creating
>   darkness.
>
> O lord of Rakshasas, these illusory powers being usued in a conflict,
>   even the Devas and Asuras shall not be able to perceive his course.
>   Besides he has obtained a **quiver**, the arrows whereof shall never be
>   exhausted, a **bow**, which is hard of being got by and a **dreadful weapon**
>   which destroys enemies in a conflict.

[image]
[image]
[image]

English Translation ([Source](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-34))

> And having resorted to the **illusory powers, conferred upon him in
>   yore by Pasupati** he entered into the enemies camp and belaboured
>   them. Being **invisible** in the welkin by virtue of his illusory
>   powers and having brought Indra under the influence thereof he struck
>   him with hundreds of arrows. When Ravana's son came to know that Indra
>   was exhausted he, having bound him up by **virtue of illusion**,
>   proceeded towards his army. That conqueror of Sakra and subduer of
>   enemies, conversant with illusory powers, was **not visible**, by
>   whom, Indra, although master of many illusions, was carried away by
>   force.

**2 Along with those weapons and boons he got siddhis and a boon of invincibility (in special conditions) from Lord Bhrahma:**

[image]

[image]

**English Translation** ([Source](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-35))

> Thereupon the highly powerful Indrajit the subduer of enemies, said
>   "If dost thou say so, O god, I pray for immortality."Thereat the
>   highly powerfulpatriarch said to Meghanada "There is none perfectly
>   immortal on earth amongst created beings birds, quadrupeds and other
>   highly powerful beings." Hearing the words uttered by the grand father
>   the highly powerful Meghanada said to the eternal lord "Hear, then,
>   what I want in exchange for releasing Sakra. **May a chariot with horses
>   rise up from fire when I shall offer sacrifices unto it, being
>   desirous of vanquishing my enemies in the conflict. And may I be
>   immortal as long as I shall remain on that car. This is the boon I
>   have resolved upon praying for. May I meet with destruction, O deity,
>   whenever I shall engage in fight without finishing my offerings unto
>   fire**. All others, O god, attain to immortality by virtue of devout
>   penances but 1 shall acquire that by dint of my own prowess." Whereto
>   the grand father replied saying "so be it".

Comment: Here: http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/source:ramayana

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Thanks for the link! added English translation from this source...

Comment: @YDS Indianscriptures.com has translations of many scriptures verse by verse.