# Who is the Rakshasa named Ravani in Ramayan?

Tags: ramayana, rakshasa

Who is the Rakshasa named Ravani in Ramayan?

Is Ravani the charitor of Ravan or the son of Ravan?

It is said that Ravani was more powerful than Ravan and sometimes he bounds Indra with his magical powers while fighting between gods and Rakhasas.

Is there any relationship between Ravan and Ravani?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Who is the Rakhas named Ravani in Ramayan? Is Ravani the charitor of Ravan or the son of Ravan? Is there any relationship between Ravan and Ravani?**

Ravani was **Meghanada** (Indrajit) the son of Ravana. This is same as how Drona's son Ashwatthama is also called Drauni.

As per [Yuddha Kanda of Valmiki Ramayana](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga44/yuddha_44_frame.htm):

> सो अन्तर्धान गतह् पापो **रावणी** रण कर्कशाः | ब्रह्म दत्त वरो वीरो रावणिह्
>   क्रोध मूर्चितः || ६-४४-३५
>
> That **Ravani (Indrajit the son of Ravana)**, the sinful demon who had gone out of sight and was cruel in battle, rendered himself as invisible again and hurled forth sharp arrows, bright as lightning.

All the sons of Ravana can be called Ravani but the son who bounds Indra was Meghanada.

As per ***Uttar Kand of Valmiki Ramayana***:

[image]

> Thereupon ascending his car **Ravani (Ravana's son Meghanada)**, beside himself with rage, entered the dreadful flank.
>
> And having resorted to the illusory powers, conferred upon him in yore
>   by Pasupati he entered into the enemies camp and belaboured them.

[image]

> When **Ravani (Ravana's son Meghanada)** came to know that Indra was exhausted he, having bound him up by virtue of illusion, proceeded towards his army.

Later Meghanada came to be known as Indrajit.

**Was Meghanada (Indrajit) more powerful than Ravana?**

In these shlokas of **Uttarkanda of Valmiki Ramayana**, Sages tell Rama that Ravani (Indrajit) was more powerful than Ravana:

[image]

> To defeat Ravana in battle was (for thee) a small matter ;but it is a piece of good fortune that Ravani (Ravana's son Indrajit), who had confronted thee for combat, hath been slain (by thee) in battle. By good fortune it is that thou, O mighty armed one, hadst been liberated from (the bonds of) that foe of the Devas whose course resembled that of Time and that thou also hadst secured victory.
>
> Hearing of the destruction of Indrajit, we congratulate thee (on thy
>   success). He was incapable of being slain by all creatures, and in
>   battle possessed mighty powers of illusion. Hearing that Indrajit
>   slain, amazement hath seized us all.

[image]

> Having regard to his Indrajit's energy and might, I shall relate unto thee the reason, in the light of which thou wilt perceive why Ravana's son had been capable of slaying his enemies, but could not himself be slain by them.

The reason why Meghanada was more powerful than Ravana is described in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22789/12304).

Comment: Also here - Book VI : Yuddha Kanda - Book Of War.
सो अन्तर्धान गतह् पापो रावणी रण कर्कशाः |
ब्रह्म दत्त वरो वीरो रावणिह् क्रोध मूर्चितः || ६-४४-३५
35. saH raavaNiH = that Indrajit the son of Ravana; saH - 
http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga44/yuddha_44_frame.htm

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Thanks for the shloka!..added in the answer..

Comment: Ok ,Also do State in answer that Ravani is actually Indrajeet.That will make things more clear and the english shlokas for those who don't know sanskrit.:-)

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Done... :)

Comment: Oh.. ravani is indrajeet's name. Thanks @SwiftPushkar and thanks for your answer.

Comment: I wonder why Ravana could not do the same............ he also had powers of illusion, yet he was defeated by Indra?

Comment: @ThePhone999 Meghanada had more powers of illusion than Ravana, please see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22789/12304